Unable to View Pub/Sub Metrics with Monitoring Viewer and Pub/Sub Viewer Roles
I am experiencing an issue where I am unable to view Pub/Sub metrics despite having the Monitoring Viewer (roles/monitoring.viewer) and Pub/Sub Viewer (roles/pubsub.viewer) roles.
I have permission like Monitoring Viewer (roles/monitoring.viewer) and Pub/Sub Viewer (roles/pubsub.viewer) roles. I expect to be able to view Pub/Sub metrics.

Your statements aren't supported by any evidence. Please update your question to show (a) that the identity that you are using has these roles; and (b) that using the identity does not permit you to view the metrics

Hi @Kha, If you want to check your PubSub metrics you can follow the steps mentioned in the documentation. Does this helps you?
